# Solspace Freeform plugin: AJAX without jQuery – how?

Tags: ajax, plugin-freeform, solspace

I am trying to post data using AJAX.

The docs describes a method [here](https://solspace.com/craft/freeform/docs/ajax-forms/). But that is mainly for jQuery.

I have also looked at [this url](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/25347/solspace-freeform-how-to-send-file-via-ajax-with-freeform), which also uses jQuery.

But from what I understand, the "action" parameter in `<input type="hidden" name="action" value="freeform/api/form">`is where the data is sent. But if I send data to that URL, I get a 404.

How do I properly submit a form using AJAX?

Answer (score 1):

From the action you are currently posting to a controller [see here](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/controllers)

The example shows that in your case it would be looking for a plugin called "Freeform" with a controller named "api" and then within that controller there would need to be a "form" action.  If this isn't there then the page will return a 404 or error as it cannot find the route.

You may be able to create the same thing without using jQuery with something like [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery)